# Create new column based on another column for a multi-index Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, multi-index

I'm running Python 3.5 on Windows and writing code to study financial econometrics.

I have a multi-index panda dataframe where the level=0 index is a series of month-end dates and the level=1 index is a simple integer ID. I want to create a new column of values ('new_var') where for each month-end date, I look forward 1-month and get the values from another column ('some_var') and of course the IDs from the current month need to align with the IDs for the forward month. Here is a simple test case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create some time series data
id = np.arange(0,5)
date = [pd.datetime(2017,1,31)+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(i) for i in [0,1]]

my_data = []
for d in date:
    for i in id:
        my_data.append((d, i, np.random.random()))

df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=['date', 'id', 'some_var'])

df['new_var'] = np.nan
df.set_index(['date', 'id'], inplace=True)

# Drop an observation to reflect my true data
df.drop(('2017-02-28',3), level=None, inplace=True)

df

# The desired output....
list1 = df.loc['2017-01-31'].index.labels[1].tolist()
list2 = df.loc['2017-02-28'].index.labels[1].tolist()
common = list(set(list1) & set(list2))

for i in common:
    df.loc[('2017-01-31', i)]['new_var'] = df.loc[('2017-02-28', i)]['some_var']

df
```

I feel like there is a better way to get my desired output. Maybe I should just embrace the "for" loop? Maybe a better solution is to reset the index?

Thank you,

F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a integer column representing the date, substrate one from it (to shift it by one month) and the merge the value left on back to the original dataframe.

```
Out[28]: 
               some_var
date       id          
2017-01-31 0   0.736003
           1   0.248275
           2   0.844170
           3   0.671364
           4   0.034331
2017-02-28 0   0.051586
           1   0.894579
           2   0.136740
           4   0.902409
df = df.reset_index()
df['n_group'] = df.groupby('date').ngroup()
df_shifted = df[['n_group', 'some_var','id']].rename(columns={'some_var':'new_var'})
df_shifted['n_group'] = df_shifted['n_group']-1
df = df.merge(df_shifted, on=['n_group','id'], how='left')
df = df.set_index(['date','id']).drop('n_group', axis=1)
Out[31]: 
               some_var   new_var
date       id                    
2017-01-31 0   0.736003  0.051586
           1   0.248275  0.894579
           2   0.844170  0.136740
           3   0.671364       NaN
           4   0.034331  0.902409
2017-02-28 0   0.051586       NaN
           1   0.894579       NaN
           2   0.136740       NaN
           4   0.902409       NaN
```

Comment: that worked and appears to be very efficient. Thank you.